# noUiSlider.js is not working in the magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, magento-2.1.3

My sited loaded `noUiSlider.js`  in the template file in custom module but when I call the function in my custom js I was getting this error:

**ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined**

In this code

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
(function($){
$(window).on("resize load", toggleNav);
        var textLineHeight = $("#text-line-height").get(0);
        noUiSlider.create(textLineHeight,  {start: 0, range:{'min': 1, 'max': 5}, connect: 'lower'});
});
```

Can you help me how I fix this error in Magento2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you didn't add `noUiSlider` js to require js:

For example, your `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {

    map: {
        '*': {
            noUiSlider:
                'Vendor_Module/js/noUiSlider'
        }
    }

};
```

Your code lines:

```
require(['jquery', 'noUiSlider'],function($, noUiSlider){
  //Your code here
});
```

Comment: If you need the slider to be initialised on page load you can add `domReady!` as a dependency btw, then there's no need for the jQuery shorthand and any other modules that depend on this module will also wait until page load.

Comment: @BenCrook so, we don't need jquery if we add `domReady!`?

Comment: thanks for reply where i make requirejs-config.js in root ?

Comment: It should be `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` in your module.

Comment: getting same error again

Comment: @Rahulocodewire I have just updated my answer.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh You'll still need jQuery, you just don't need the `(function($){});` shorthand - I presume you added that as a shorthand for document ready anyway. If not then ignore me :P

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh  i am getting this error  "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/version1486462969/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Vendor_Module/js/noUiSlider.js

Comment: @Rahulocodewire did you run static content deploy again?

Comment: i deployed many time but same error again

Comment: @Rahulocodewire You can update your question with what tried again.

Comment: You might need to delete `var/view_preprocessed`, `pub/static/requirejs/` and `pub/static/frontend/` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: getting  this Error: Script error for: Vendor_Module/lib/nouislider/nouislider
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror  please tell me how i remove this error

Comment: @Rahulocodewire You need to change `Vendor_Module` to the module that contains your slider.